# How to convert date object to timestamp in client?

Tags: oracle

for example

```
select to_timestamp(sysdate) from dual
```

return date object, not timestamp. 
I try to change

```
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='ss.ff'
```

but select return error.

Comment: `to_timestamp` converts a **varchar** to a timestamp. Using it on a `date` is *totally* useless. Use `current_timestamp` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting with `sysdate` then as @a_horse_with_no_name says you don't need to do a conversrion; use `systimestamp` or `current_timestamp` instead. (One is the server time, one is the client time, which will be the same unless your client is in a different timezone).

More generally though you can [cast between data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions023.htm):

```
select cast(date_field as timestamp) from your_table
```

You won't add any precision to the value though; the date already have a time down to second precision, even if that is midnight; and your timestamp will still have the fractional seconds part as zero.

If you just want to display your `DATE` as a string but show the time it already has then you need to specify the output format, e.g.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```